# How to optimize further our mongoDB aggregate?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance

We're trying to speed up one of our mongoDB aggregates. All of our collections are historical (we don't update, just get the latest entry based on the ID)

However, it slows down at around 2500 entries (50 seconds).

How can I improve it further?

All collections already have indexes that are being used on the lookup aggregates.

This is summary of our aggregate.

```
db.table.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $and: [ attributes based on unique ids ]
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        30 fields
    }
}
{
    $match: {
        $and: [ attributes based on 30 fields ]
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        x6 (all with pipelines)
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        30 fields,
        arrayElemAt 0 lookups 
    }
}
{
    $match: {
        $and: [ attributes based on lookups ]
    }
}])
```

Is it possible to have a response time at around 5-10 seconds?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here for anyone to help you. Sharing an `explain`, your actual queries, and the indexes you're using would help people debug what's going on. `explain` should hopefully point to which stage is slow & let folks focus on that

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use `explain`. We executed the aggregate with `explain('executionStats')`. On each execution, we added in the stages one by one. We saw that a lookup was causing the performance issue and now know how to deal with it. Thank you!

Comment: great! glad you were able to solve it :)